# A automorphism contradiction

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let group $G=\{1, a, b, x, y, z\}$ and $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $G$ such that $$\alpha(1)=1;$$ $$\alpha(a)=b,  \alpha(b)=a;$$ $$\alpha(x)=y, \alpha(y)=z, \alpha(z)=x $$

**My question** is:

\begin{align}
\alpha(\alpha(a))=\alpha(b)=b\text{ gives } \alpha^2=1 \text{ i.e. it is an automorphism of order } 2;
\end{align}

whereas$$\alpha(\alpha(\alpha(x)))=x \text{ gives } \alpha^3=1 \text{ i.e. it is an automorphism of order } 3. $$

It is a contradicting conclusion. What have I missed? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be an automorphism  of order $2$,, if one had $\alpha(\alpha(g))=g$  for *all* $g\in G$. Where do you see it is true? Similarly for order $3$.

Comment: @Bernard thanks, then what is the order of $\alpha$ in my example?

Comment: The l.c.m. of $2$ and $3$ – $6$.

Comment: There are two problems with this. Firstly, your reasoning actually shows that $\alpha$ has order $6$, which is not in itself a contradiction. The second problem is that there are (up to isomorphism) only two groups of order $6$, and neither of them has an automorphism of order $6$, so your definition of $\alpha$ must be wrong.

Comment: Is $G$ supposed to be a group? Your use of the word "automorphism" strongly suggests that you intend for $G$ to have some structure beyond being a mere set. Your use of the letter $G$ suggests that you intend for it to be a group. But nothing in the question says that these suggestions are really your intentions.  If you intended $G$ to be a group, then @DerekHolt has answered your question in his comment.

Comment: Addendum to previous comment: The tag "group theory" also suggests that $G$ should be a group, but it could also refer to the fact that the automorphisms of anything form a group.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks, $G$ is a group indeed, and I had clearly  knew that Derek answered my question perfectly. It was my mistake to have forgotten to add the key word “group”, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You only get that $\alpha^2(a)=a$ and $\alpha^2(b)=b$. Similarly, for $t\in\{x,y,z\}$, $\alpha^3(t)=t$.

This is not a contradiction.

Note that, for every automorphism $\beta$ of a group $\Gamma$,
$$
\{x\in\Gamma:\beta(x)=x\}
$$
is a subgroup of $\Gamma$.

Can you finish? Hint: $\alpha$ cannot exist.